# silverstripe 4 - Render UserDefinedForm on custom page templates

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I need some help with converting SS3 to SS4. I would like to render my contact form on another page as well as my default Contact page. I managed to get it working in SS3 but things are a little different in SS4 and I am not sure how to write the function or where to put it. I have tried a bunch of combinations and locations but I need help.

In SS3 I created my UserDefineForm page with its fields. I then added the following to the custom page that I wanted the form to render too:

class IndexPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

```
// Sign up form
public function SignupForm(){
    $get = DataObject::get_one('SiteTree', "URLSegment = 'contact-me'");
   return new UserDefinedForm_Controller($get);
}
```

}

What/Where do I put the function in SS4 to get the form fields to render on the custom page template as it does on the Contact us page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work.

```
public function getSignupForm()
    {
        $page = \SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm::get()->filter('URLSegment', 'contact-me')->first();
        $controller = \SilverStripe\UserForms\Control\UserDefinedFormController::create($page);
        return $controller->Form();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to tweak it slightly and this is working for me now.

public function Form()
    {
        $page = \SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm::get()->filter(['URLSegment' => 'contact-me'])->First();
  $controller = \SilverStripe\UserForms\Control\UserDefinedFormController::create($page);
        return $controller->Form();
    }